# Difficulty in Training a Question-Answering Model

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, nlp

I'm trying to train a simple deep learning model for question-answering, but I'm not getting good results. As you can see in the code below, the model contains:

- An embedding layer that generates a token and positional embedding for the src input.
- A transformer encoder.
- A decoder in the form of a
  linear layer, which takes the output of the encoder and generate
  logits from it.

The model takes in input a batch of tokenized sentences of shape (batch_size, max_length). The embedding and the encoder's output are of shape (batch_size, max_length, vocab_size) and the generated tokens are of shape (batch_size, max_length). The model is then trained with cross entropy loss.

For the tokenization, I don't include  and , there is only  token for padding, and  for unknown words. That's because I think the model will learn to generate a padded sequence, so there's no need to use them, plus it always generates a sequence of length max_length.

```
class Model(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self,
                 vocab_size,
                 hidden_size,
                 max_length,
                 pad_id,
                 num_encoder_layers: int = 2,
                 layer_norm_eps: float = 1e-5):
        super(Model, self).__init__()

        self.pad_id = pad_id

        self.embeddings = Embedding(
            vocab_size=vocab_size,
            hidden_size=hidden_size,
            max_position_embeddings=max_length,
            pad_token_id=pad_id
        )

        encoder_layer = TransformerEncoderLayer(hidden_size, num_encoder_layers)
        encoder_norm = LayerNorm(hidden_size, eps=layer_norm_eps)
        self.encoder = TransformerEncoder(encoder_layer, num_encoder_layers, encoder_norm)

        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, vocab_size)

    def forward(self, src, trg=None):
        src_embeddings = self.embeddings(src)

        output = self.encoder(src_embeddings)
        logits = self.fc(output)

        if trg is not None:
            loss = F.cross_entropy(
                input=logits.view(-1, logits.size(-1)),
                target=trg.view(-1),
            )
        else:
            loss = None

        predicted_ids = torch.argmax(logits, dim=-1)

        return predicted_ids, loss
```

What I'm doing wrong? The generated sequences are too bad, even when the validation loss is low. (If you decided to answer, please provide a detailed answer. I'm having a hard time detecting what's wrong)

Note:

- I think the data is enough to train this model.
- The model is big enough to computer pattern's in the data.
- I toyed with different hyperparams.
- The loss curves don't show any overfitting.

Comment: As it may be a modeling bug and not a bug in the code, I'd see this question more fit in [datascience.se](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/). However, this is a sequence-to-sequence task, but in this case you have a potentially deep encoder and a decoder made only by a single Linear layer. Secondly, you did not include the generation code, i.e how you generate output tokens from predicted_ids, so I cannot tell if there are bugs  in that code.

Comment: I use the same forward for generation (probably no the best thing to do). I also agree the decoder should be also a transformer. And I found out the I was not specifying the batch first in the TransformerEncoderLayer.

Comment: I'd say that most issues are in the tokenization, generation and modeling details and not in the code. I'd suggest to close this question and reopen it on [datascience.se](https://datascience.stackexchange.com) if you want a lengthy answer.